# How to change css class property after X button is clicked to transparent

Tags: javascript, css

What I want to do is have the `.curtain` class background color change after the exit button is clicked.

The current background of `.curtain` is: `background: #0a0a0a;`

How would I have the background to `.curtain` change to something different, after the exit button is clicked?

https://jsfiddle.net/aqdjL3m7/

```
.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}
```

After the exit button is clicked, the iframe video is removed. That can be seen in the jsfiddle.

After the iframe is removed from `.curtain`, this background is showing:

```
background: #0a0a0a;
```

I want that background to change to something different.

I want to change the background of `.curtain` to something different after the exit button is clicked.

How do I do that in the code?

The exit button appears on the screen after the curtains are open.

[image]

```js
/*jslint devel: true */

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};
  const body = document.body;
  var originalEvent = "";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function hideBackground(background) {
      background.classList.add("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(hideBackground);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function hideButton(button) {
      button.classList.add("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(hideButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  function markAsPlayed(played) {
    played.classList.add("played");
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function animationEndHandler2(evt) {

    const animationName = evt.animationName;

    if (animationName === "initial-fade") {
      coverClickHandlerContinue(originalEvent);
    }
  }

  function coverClickHandlerContinue(originalEvent) {
    body.classList.remove("initial-fade");
    hideAll(config.containers);
    resetPage();
    markAsPlayed(originalEvent);
    const cover = originalEvent;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    originalEvent = evt.currentTarget;
    body.classList.add("initial-fade");
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
    body.addEventListener("animationend", animationEndHandler2);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {
  const body = document.body;

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function showBackground(background) {
      background.classList.remove("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(showBackground);
  }

  function resetCurtains(curtainSelector) {
    const allCurtains = document.querySelectorAll(curtainSelector);

    function showCurtain(curtain) {
      curtain.classList.remove("active");
    }
    allCurtains.forEach(showCurtain);
  }

  function showAllButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function animationEndHandler(evt) {

    const animationName = evt.animationName;

    if (animationName === "fadingOut") {
      fadeReset();
    }
  }

  function fadeReset() {
    body.classList.remove("fadingOut");
    resetBackground("body");
    resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
    showAllButtons(".hide");
    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  function resetPage() {
    body.classList.add("fadingOut");
  }

  function exitClickHandler() {
    resetPage();
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addExitHandlers(callback) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", callback);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
    body.addEventListener("animationend", animationEndHandler);
  }

  return {
    addExitHandlers,
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    return player;
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
    playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
    playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
    playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
    playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;

    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {

  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 0,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  };
  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
  }

  function createCallback(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    return function callback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function playerAdder(parent, playerOptions) {
    const wrapper = parent.querySelector(".wrap");
    return function callback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function removePlayer(wrapper) {
    wrapper.player.destroy();
    delete wrapper.player;
  }

  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");
    if (wrapper.player) {
      return removePlayer(wrapper);
    }
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    show(wrapper);
    const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    wrapper.player = player;
  }

  return {
    adder: playerAdder,
    createCallback,
    removePlayerHandler
  };
}());

const players = (function coverUIPlayerFacade() {

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const parent = document.querySelector(coverSelector).parentElement;
    const callback = managePlayer.adder(parent, playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, callback);
  }

  function init() {
    manageCover.init({
      container: ".container",
      playButton: ".thePlay"
    });

    manageUI.init({});
    manageUI.addExitHandlers(managePlayer.removePlayerHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

players.init();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  players.add(".playa", {});
  players.add(".playb", {});
  players.add(".playc", {});
  players.add(".playd", {});
  players.add(".playe", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  players.add(".playf", {});
  players.add(".playg", {});
  players.add(".playh", {});
  players.add(".playi", {});

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
background: #353198;

 }

.initial-fade {
  animation: initial-fade 500ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes initial-fade {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.initial-fade,
.fadingOut{
  cursor: default;
}
.initial-fade .thePlay,
.initial-fade .thePlay * {
  pointer-events: none !important;
 
}


.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 290px;
  gap: 10px; 
}

.outer.isOpen {
  /*display: flex;*/
  width: auto;
  /*align-content: stretch;*/
}

.fadingOut .isOpen {
  animation: fadingOut 1s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes fadingOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

/*body*/.bg1 {
  animation: fadeInBody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeInBody {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/*body*/.bg1 .with-curtain:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
}

.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

.thePlay {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.played {
  fill: green;
}

button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fadeInExit 1s forwards 7.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

@keyframes fadeInExit {
  99% {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    pointer-events: initial;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit svg {
  fill: red;
  transition: fill 3s ease;
}

.exit:hover svg,
.fadingOut .exit svg {
  fill: green;
}

.fadingOut .exit {
  animation: fadeOutExit 8s forwards;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes fadeOutExit {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1-open 8s forwards 520ms;
}

@keyframes curtain1-open {
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2-open 8s forwards 520ms;
}

@keyframes curtain2-open {
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
  }
}

.fadingOut .container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1-close 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes curtain1-close {
  from {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.fadingOut .container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2-close 8s forwards;
}

@keyframes curtain2-close {
  from {
    transform: translateX(calc(100% - 1px));
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="container play1 with-curtain">
      <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <g id="play">
               <title>Play</title>
               <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
               <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
            </g>
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <g id="exit">
                  <title>exit</title>
                  <path class="exitHover" d="m-101.116-101.116a143 143 0 11202.232 202.232a143 143 0 01-202.232-202.232zzzz" fill="red" />
                  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="113" />
                  <path class="exitHover" fill="blue" d="m-101.116-101.116m169.705 11.313a113 113 0 00-137.178 0l68.589 68.59zm-158.392 21.214a113 113 0 000 137.178l68.59-68.589zm21.214 158.392a113 113 0 00137.178 0l-68.589-68.59zm158.392-21.214a113 113 0 000-137.178l-68.59 68.589z" />
               </g>
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play2 with-curtain">
      <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play3 with-curtain">
      <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play4 with-curtain">
      <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain4">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play5 with-curtain">
      <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain5">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play6 with-curtain">
      <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain6">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play7 with-curtain">
      <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain7">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play8 with-curtain">
      <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain8">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container play9 with-curtain">
      <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <use href="#play" />
         </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain9">
         <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sliding-panels">
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-144 -144 288 288">
               <use href="#exit" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get the .curtain element using `let curtain = document.getElementsByClassName("curtain")` and then change the background as in the answer from @OmriAttiya using `curtain.style.backgroundColor = "whatever"`

Comment: I still wasn't able to do this. Can you provide a working code example in an answer?

Comment: I have taken a closer look at your jsfiddle and there is an easier solution. If you want the background to have the same colour every time you click the exit button you can also add the following to your css document: `body.fadingOut .curtain {background-colour: whatever;}`. Since you give the body a class of fadingOut when the exit button is clicked. Is this what you are looking for?